# DELETE FROM multiple tables?

Tags: php

Anyone have an idea on how to delete from multiple tables in one query? I have been scratching my head endless trying to find a way to make this work. But my endless search on google havnet helped..

I have a delete button on my site that needs to delete from multiple tables.. Right now, it uses the code to delete from the the table "tilbehor"

```
DELETE FROM tilbehor WHERE t_id = '$id'
```

But I also need it to delete from the table "kategori"

In the kategori table i have the 3 columns "id", "p_id" and "t_id". I need it all to be deleted where "t_id" = the $id from the query

Comment: Do a search for "transactions".

Comment: Which db engine are u using? You can also solve this by doing dinamic SQL, for example by creation a collection of table names, and iterating over it, so on the same query changing only the table name. A bit dirty, yes. Another option it would be to create an stored procedure.

Comment: Add a foreign key constraint

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3
WHERE t1.t_id=t2.t_id AND t2.t_id=t3.t_id;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If the `t_id` is the main ID. You could look into [Foreign keys](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) and use on DELETE Cascade. Foreign keys are connected with a primary key from another table. When the matching primary key of the table is deleted, the rows on other tables that match the foreign key with the primary key are deleted as well

Comment: I cant use foreign keys. They are not connected from another table. Its a way to "link" a product to accessories. So the "kategori" table has a p_id a lot of the t_id's so that on the webpage when you wonna se a certain product(p_id) the page knows wich accessories to show(t_id) - But when you delete an accessorie it needs to delete the connection from the table in the database. And so it needs to DELETE all FROM tilbehor AND kategori where t_id = '$id'..

Comment: @KristianTarp Aha ok well I couldn't understand that from the question you asked. I'm gonna keep this answer on here for future visitors that are actually looking for this.